# MovieClip coordinates

Tags: flash, actionscript, movieclip

I am relatively new to actionscript but here is the dilemma I am currently having issues with.  I currently have a large movieclip acting as a container.  Inside this movieclip, I have a variety of other movieclips.  I currently have my code moving the banner right or left depending on the position of the mouse.  What I would like to do is get the coordinates of the child movieclips so I can manipulate certain animations when they reach a specific point on the screen.  However, when i try accessing the X and Y variables by doing the following:

```
trace(movieClip_1.childMovieClip.x)
```

the values do not change since they are sticking to the local variables within the parent movieclip.

All help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this!

```
var point:Point = new Point(childMovieClip.x, childMovieClip.y);
point = localToGlobal(point);
trace('Child coords: ' + point);
```

and take a look at the documentation -> [localToGlobal](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#localToGlobal%28%29)

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply.  I tried inserting the above code into my onEnterFrame, however, the coordinates do not change when the banner moves left and right.  After further investigation, I believe the localToGlobal approach is what I am looking for.  Unfortunately, it still is not working as expected.

Comment: It's defenatly what you're looking for ;) depending where u instatiate the child u might want to address it like so.new Point( movieClip_1.childMovieClip.x, movieClip_1.childMovieClip.y)